# Mendix custom CSS to place paging buttons at bottom of template grid wipes popup when clicking to first or last page

Tags: css, widget, popup, mendix

I'm not sure who here is familiar with using custom CSS styling within the Mendix Low-Code Development platform, but I'm running low on ideas so I figured it was worth the shot.

So for the app we’re working on, one of the things we have is a popup that comes up that users can input information on. It has an autocomplete widget, two date pickers, a radio buttons widget, and a template grid, and then below all of these input widgets are two buttons (Continue and Cancel). The template grid has the paging buttons active on it, and has some custom CSS styling active on it to set it to a specific height, enable y-axis scrolling on autoflow, and move the paging buttons to the bottom of the template grid instead of the top.

Clicking to go anywhere but the first or last page works fine, however clicking the “last page” button, or clicking the “next page” button to go to the last page, will result in everything but the template grid, and the continue and cancel buttons disappearing, and the template grid’s height shrinks to an unusable level. In the opposite direction, clicking the “first page” button, or clicking the “previous page” button to go the the first page, will result in essentially the entire popup being wiped out, with all the input widgets and action buttons disappearing, and leaving just a white page.

After looking around, it seems it’s due to some custom CSS that I had taken from a Mendix community forum post that I used to move the paging buttons on the template grid to the bottom of the grid as opposed to the top that’s causing the issue. If it’s because of issues with the paging buttons trying to readjust, is there a way to edit this CSS code so that these issues do not happen? The CSS code I used is shown below, any critiques on it would be super appreciated. Thank you!

```
.mx-grid.mx-templategrid{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.mx-grid-searchbar{
  order: 1;
}

.mx-grid-controlbar{
  order: 2;
}

.mx-grid-content{
  order: 1;
}
```